# asp.net refresh web page on DB changes

Tags: asp.net, ajax, database, session

I'm currently working on an asp.net website. 
I have a page (main.aspx) which displays records from a database table. Another page (editing.aspx) is responsible for editing records in the DB table.

let's assume we have a scenario where two users are using the website, user1 (on session1) is viewing the records in main.aspx, user2 (on session2) is editing the DB table from editing.aspx, what I want is: to refresh main.aspx for user1 when user2 saves his changes to the DB table.

I tried using an AJAX timer that pulls the DB for changes every 10 seconds, and refreshes an UpdatePanel (in which I'm displaying the records), and it works just fine, but I want to know if there'se a better way than pulling the DB server for changes.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is debatable if the other way is better but what you are looking for is persistent connection to the server that lets the server send e message to the page. There is a good library for .NET called [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) that abstracts away the details. It is certainly more network efficient but depending on your use case the update panel may be good enough. Basically with SignalR you will send a message from the server-side code of your edit page which would be received by a JavaScript function on your main page. Then you either show the data or cause a refresh in some way.

Comment: thanks, SignalR is indeed a good library. however, polling turn out to be the solution for my problem and as you said (update panel is good enough)