# Refresh gridview after remote update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview on an ASP page displayed on www.myurl.com/page1. It displays data that can be modified by other computers using a different page (www.myurl.com/page2) on the same website. I'd like to make it such that when user 1 adds data, the gridview on user 2's page refreshes with the new data (but it's not the same exact data).

Is there a way that the gridview can be notified of a data update? Or do I just resort to 10 second refreshes (which I'd like to avoid)?

Comment: you can use signalR to get notified.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ajax UpdatePanel in your application which works like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Use an Ajax timer control along with the gridview in the UpdatePanel to refresh the grid for every 5/10 seconds. In this way, only the gridview part of it gets refreshed and not the entire page.

http://www.devcurry.com/2009/03/how-to-refresh-aspnet-gridview.html.

Possible duplicate question : [asp.net refresh web page on DB changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704517/asp-net-refresh-web-page-on-db-changes)